# Method "POST" not allowed with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I'm trying to create a JSON API compliant rest service using Django Rest Framework JSON API:
https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

I think I'm stuck at the Django Rest Framework level, but I am not certain.

I think the GET request is working, but the POST is not because I get this response:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json; indent=2' -X POST http://localhost:8000/greeters/
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed.",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data"
      },
      "status": "405"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the GET is fine:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json; indent=2' http://localhost:8000/greeters/
{
  "data": {}
}
```

I've looked at other posts and the tutorials and it seems like I've missed something in my code that is not popping out at me.  Hopefully, it will pop out at someone else who has more experience with Djang and Django Rest Framework.

Thank you for your time :)

Here's my code:

my_project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^greeters/', include('greeter.urls')),
]
```

greeter/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import GreeterViewSet

ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'^', GreeterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

greeter/views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Greeter
from .serializers import GreeterSerializer


class GreeterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """API endpoints for Greeter"""

    queryset = Greeter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GreeterSerializer

    # I've tried adding these methods in but none of it worked
    #def perform_create(self, serializer):
    #    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    #def create(self, request):
    #    print('#########create')

    #def post(self, request):
    #    print('#########post')
```

greeter/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Greeter


class GreeterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """Define Greeter serializer"""

    class Meta:
        model = Greeter
        fields = ('message')
```

greeter/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Greeter(models.Model):
    """Define Greeter model"""
    id = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=200
    )
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Update:

Thank you for the help. It has guided me to the solution.

I removed `greeter/urls.py` and moved all of the url configurations into `my_project/urls.py`.

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from greeter.views import GreeterViewSet

ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'greeters', GreeterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

It works, but I would still like to understand how to push all of the greeter url code into a file inside the greeter folder, like `greeter/urls.py`.

I've opened up a separate question to get guidance on that so I can mark this as answered.

[In Django, how do you keep a module's url configurations encapsulated inside the module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267547/in-django-how-do-you-keep-a-modules-url-configurations-encapsulated-inside-the)

Thanks again for all of the help :)

Comment: You've commented out the `post()` method of your view... By default, Django REST will return a 405 if there's not a method that corresponds to the HTTP request method.

Comment: @wpercy that's for the help.  I had each of those methods uncommented at one point, but it was the same result.  I listed it there to show some things I've tried.  Is there anything else I could be missing?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have an empty prefix in your router; so the URL for the "root" view of the viewset is the same as the list/create view. Try removing the "greeters" prefix from the base urls.py and using it as the router prefix instead.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman for your help.  I didn't quite understand what you were saying without example code, but my error was in the general area of what you mentioned.  I added an update with code of what worked.  I'm still not sure how to keep 2 separate urls.py files.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some *API prefix* to your url include statement as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'sample', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

Thus your end-point will be, **`/greeters/sample/`** for list-api (HTTP GET) and create api (HTTP POST)

Comment: Thanks @JPG for your help.  I've updated the question with working code.  Would you happen to know how I can keep two separate urls.py files?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267547/in-django-how-do-you-keep-a-modules-url-configurations-encapsulated-inside-the