# In Django, how do you keep a module's url configurations encapsulated inside the module?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, json-api

Currently, I import url configurations into my Django project with:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from greeter.views import GreeterViewSet

ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'greeters', GreeterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

Is there a way where I can move these parts of the code:

```
ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'greeters', GreeterViewSet)
```

into a separate file in `greeter/urls.py`?

And still keep these URLs:

- GET /greeter/ to fetch list of greeters
- POST /greeter/ to create a new greeter

I have tried:

my_project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^greeters/', include('greeter.urls')),
]
```

greeter/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import GreeterViewSet

ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'^', GreeterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

But got:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json; indent=2' -X POST http://localhost:8000/greeters/
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed.",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data"
      },
      "status": "405"
    }
  ]
}
```

In case it helps, here is my original question that has been resolved:
[Method "POST" not allowed with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211142/method-post-not-allowed-with-django-rest-framework)

Update:

With the help of the answers, I was able to arrive at this solution:

my_project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('greeters/', include('greeter.urls')),
]
```

greeter/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import GreeterViewSet

ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'', GreeterViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

With this:

- all of the greeter url configuration is kept inside of the greeter
  module
- the project url configuration ties 'greeter' resource to the
  greeter module
- it seems like additional greeter views can be added to
  the greeter url configuration (I haven't tested this)

I think this is as good as I can get it.  Thanks again for all of the help :)

Comment: As I mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214799/8283848) please do add some ***prefix*** to the `urlpatterns` .(because that's the REST way)

Comment: The empty regex `r'^'` may cause lot's of problem. It's recomended to add ***always*** some prefix

Comment: so the only way is to have this kind of URL: /prefix/greeter/? but that seems odd to force a prefix, because most other RESTful URLs do not require a prefix: https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful
maybe I should give up on separating into 2 separate files then.  thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said to you before, the Router needs a prefix. You need to remove that prefix from your main URLs and use it in the router itself.

main:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('greeter.urls')),
]
```

app:

```
ROUTER = routers.DefaultRouter()
ROUTER.register(r'^greeter/', GreeterViewSet)

urlpatterns = ROUTER.urls
```

(Since you don't have any URLs other than the router ones, you don't need to use include there, you can just use the router urls directly.)

Also note, this whole thing is almost certainly not what you want to do; it means you can never have any URLs other than those for your viewset.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the help.  Your example code got me to what I ended up settling on.  My remaining concern is "can never have any URLs other than those for your viewset".  I hope the solution above addresses this.  Or at the very least, since the module only relates to one resource, it is okay to have just one viewset for the greeter resource.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the **`^`** (the [Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) symbol) from regex expression will do the job

```
# greeter/urls.py
# your code

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(ROUTER.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’ll give it a try.

Comment: And post back probably tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks JPG for all of your help.  This answer didn't quite get me to the final bit of code, but I do appreciate it very much.  Thanks again and take care :)